# How to make a conditional query in Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm starting with Postgress, and I need to make a query with four ids as params, these can be NULL, only the first is mandatory, so I'm trying to get a data list with data of every id. How can I check if id param  IS NOT NULL inside a WHERE condition.
I'll give you an example (not working)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_lock(
    IN p_id_1 character varying, 
    IN p_id_2 character varying DEFAULT NULL, 
    IN p_id_3 character varying DEFAULT NULL, 
    IN p_id_4 character varying DEFAULT NULL)
RETURNS SETOF character varying AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
    UPDATE stock
    SET lock = 1
    FROM  (
      SELECT s.id
      FROM  stock s
      WHERE
        (ls.id = p_id_1 or p_id_1 is null) OR
        (ls.id = p_id_2 or p_id_2 is null) OR
        (ls.id = p_id_3 or p_id_3 is null) OR
        (ls.id = p_id_4 or p_id_4 is null) AND
        ls.lock = 0
      FOR UPDATE OF s
    ) i
    WHERE i.id = stock.id;
```

Here I need to check first, if the param IS NOT NULL, and then concatenate  to the condition, with OR exp.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this query?

Comment: I'm not sure of what would happen if p_id_3 is null for example, can only ensure that p_id_1 will be come always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use [`in` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparisons.html) in the where condition

```
WHERE 
    s.id in (p_id_1, p_id_2, p_id_3, p_id_4) AND
    s.lock = 0;
```

Btw, you do not need a subquery:

```
UPDATE stock
SET lock = 1
WHERE
    id in (p_id_1, p_id_2, p_id_3, p_id_4) AND
    lock = 0;
```

does exactly the same but quicker.